# passing data into mySQL database using flask and jquery from html

Tags: jquery, html, flask

Hi guys I am trying to pass information from and HTML page into a MySQL database via flask but im stuck and confused

This is my python - scores.py (Database connection is conn_db with credentials etc)

```
import mysql.connector as conn
from flask import (
render_template,
Flask,
jsonify,
request,
abort as ab
)

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='C:\\Users\\thomp\\PycharmProjects\\com661_1819_team_30\\source\\template\\')

# Credentials here in code
WHO = '*********'
PWD = '********'
DATABASE = '********'


def conn_db():
return conn.connect(user=WHO,
                    password=PWD,
                    host='**********',
                    database=DATABASE
                    )


@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('scores.html')



@app.route('/addScore', methods=['POST'])
def add_score():
cnx = conn_db()
cursor = cnx.cursor()
MatchID = request.form['matchID']
Home_Score = request.form['homeScore']
Away_Score = request.form['awayScore']

print("Updating score")
if not request.json:
    ab(400)

insert_score = "INSERT INTO scores (Match_ID, Home_Score, Away_Score) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(insert_score, (MatchID, Home_Score, Away_Score))



if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

And the following is my html file scores.html ( Posted as picture )

[image: HTML file]
[image: HTml]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have given us I suppose one of your problems is that you're not posting the contents of your input fields, but rather the DOM object itself. If you're unsure about javascript code it's always a good idea to try it out in your browser's developer console.

To fix that error just add `val()` to the submit function, e.g.
`var $matchID = $('#matchID').val()`

Also I think you should remove the trailing slash from the host parameter of your AJAX call because you defined your route in flask without it.

Two side notes:

1. You should escape the posted data to prevent [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. I believe the framework you're using provides this function `conn.escape_string()` for this purpose.
2. Prepending variable names with a dollar sign is not customary in JavaScript. I think most people prefer camelCase. Especially when using jQuery adding additional dollar signs to variables might lead to confusion.

PS: It would be very helpful if you posted a specific question or any error output that you're encountering. Also posting screenshots instead of the actual code seems unnecessary and makes it way harder to debug your problems.

Comment: Thanks, was having a hassle trying to post the code for html as it keep changing, but that seems to have done the job, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done the exact same thing, so I'll share with you what I have done to allow changing of SQL data via HTML.

Just like you I retrained information from the HTML page with a request form

```
report_name = request.form["report_name"]
```

followed by

```
cur.execute("UPDATE table SET report_name=%s", [report_name])
mysql.connection.commit()
```

I only had to update my tabled, but it might be possible to change that with Insert Into.